# Ruby regular expression end of line

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to find the variables in a string, e.g.

`"%0" can not be found. %1 Please try again %2`

I need to know how each variable ends (space, period, end of line) cause I will check for the existence of same variable in the translated version of this string. Text comes from a CSV and strings do not end with a line break.

I am able to capture them all except the ones at the end of a string with:

`reg = /[%@!][^\s]+[\s\.\z$]+/`

I thought either `$` or `\z` should match end of line but that does not seem to work. How can I capture %2 in the above scenario? (again, there is no line break at the end)

Answer (score 4):

`$` matches end-of-line, but not when used inside brackets like that.  Writing `[$]` is how you would look for the normal dollar-sign character '$'.

If the string you are searching is the exact string you listed above, try

```
reg = /^"(.*)" can not be found[.] (.*) Please try again (.*)$/
error_string =~ reg
```

Your three matching results will be stored in the special variables `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`.

Comment: Thanks bta, that is just an example string, I have thousands of that to check so I cannot really use it in the form that you sent. What about \z why that won't work in the form that I wrote?

Comment: Inside a character class, almost everything loses its special meaning. `\s` still matches all ASCII whitespace characters, but `$` just matches `$`, `\z` matches `z` (the `\` is ignored), and `.` matches `.` (whether you escape it or not).

Comment: @eakkas: Yeah, I figured the string you gave was just an example.  I was mostly just illustrating the way to use `$` and `()`.  As far as I can tell, `$` and `\z` are equivalent operators, and both lose their special meaning when placed inside `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it with a different approach. Using a positive lookahead works as the character class is not needed

```
/[%@!][\w]+(?=\s|\z|\.|\W)/
```

For the example string, this returns:

```
%0

%1

%2
```

Comment: What command/operator are you using to do the matching?  Using the expression you posted, I am only able to get a single matching element at a time.  Using `/([%@!]\w+)[^%@!]*([%@!]\w+)[^%@!]*([%@!]\w+)/` will give me all three.